# Visual Basic Case Select Inside For Next Stopping After First Iteration

Tags: for-loop, visual-studio-2015, select-case

This seems like a rather trivial thing to me and yet I can't get it to work. Does anyone have any idea why the code below simply returns a single message box with "z = 0"? Thank you so much for your help.

```
For z As Integer = 0 To 5
    Select Case z
        Case z = 0
            MsgBox("z = " & z)
        Case z = 1
            MsgBox("z = " & z)
        Case z = 5
            MsgBox("z = " & z)
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a new value to z with every case statement.

Just use:

```
For z As Integer = 0 To 5
    Select Case z
        Case 0
            MsgBox("z = " & z)
        Case 1
            MsgBox("z = " & z)
        Case 5
            MsgBox("z = " & z)
    End Select
Next
```